# How to know if an npm package can be imported with ES6 import syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules

Besides going through the documentation of the package and trial/error attempts, how can I know for sure if an npm packaged can be imported with the ES6 import syntax?

Is there a file inside the package folder that I can check?

I constantly question myself about this.

**For example:**

The `md5` package [DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) only mentions `md5 = require('md5');` but I've just tested and it works with `import md5 from 'md5'`

How can I inspect the package and know for sure?

Comment: How are you running node?  Are you using `esm` or are you using `--experimental-modules`?  You should always be able to import from a CommonJS module to an ES module: [Importing CommonJS from ESM](http://2ality.com/2019/04/nodejs-esm-impl.html#importing-commonjs-from-esm)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood your question. I'm running Node version v8.11.3 - I'm asking this in the context of importing packages to my React app. I'm also using webpack and babel and I know those imports are being transpiled to ES5. But I also know that some packages can't deal with the import syntax and other can. I'm not sure why. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: I believe that you are quite accurate with that. There are cases that the documentation for the package clear dictates on how to use the package with Es6 `import` statement. You can read up on how the `import` statement work and that might give you a clue on what you are looking out for -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Babel and webpack, you can always use `import`. Webpack is taking care of transpiling the import statements in your code to include the code from the npm packages. I can't think of any case where `import` would not work while `require` would.

Answer (score 2):

You must check if the module/package has a `dist` or a `src` folder. If the package has a `dist` folder, Then it can be imported using es6's `import` statement. Otherwise if it has a `src` folder, Then it can't be imported using es6's import statement and you must use cjs's `require` function to import such modules. If you try to import a cjs module using the `import` statement, You will get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: If it has a `dist` folder, then it should be good either way.

If it has a `src` folder, then it depends on if it was written using CommonJS or ES.

Which, to be fair, usually means written using CommonJS style and can't be simply `import`ed.